# pip uninstall doesn't know about packages in pip list (inconsistent behavior)

Tags: python, pip

I have python installed via homebrew on my mac, OS 10.9.3

I installed `scipy` 0.14.0 via `pip install -U scipy`, using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/goldsmith/7262122#comment-1190674)'s flags and the modification of `export CC=gcc`, and it was successful and shows up in my `site-packages`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  34 olga  admin   1.1K Jun 17 21:01 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy
lrwxr-xr-x   1 olga  admin    84B Mar  8 13:51 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.13.1-py2.7.egg-info -> ../../../Cellar/scipy/0.13.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.13.1-py2.7.egg-info
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  admin   238B Jun 17 21:01 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.14.0-py2.7.egg-info
```

However, when I try to `pip install` a local package that requires `scipy>=0.14.0`, it keeps downloading and reinstalling! So I'm trying to figure out why my recent version of scipy is not getting detected.

`pip list` shows only version 0.13.1:

```
olgas-mbp-1378:~ olga$ pip show scipy
... packages removed for brevity...
scipy (0.13.1)
... packages removed for brevity ...
```

`pip show` is also unaware of version 0.14.0

```
olgas-mbp-1378:~ olga$ pip show scipy
---
Name: scipy
Version: 0.13.1
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires:
```

And `pip uninstall` doesn't know about *any* version of `scipy`!

```
olgas-mbp-1378:~ olga$ pip uninstall scipy
Can't uninstall 'scipy'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

What's going on here? Really hope it's something simple that I'm missing.

FYI, I get the same results whether I do `pip` or `sudo pip`.

Comment: The behaviour looks like the 0.14+ installation fails. Isn't there some error message or is the installation process finished correctly?

Comment: I had to `sudo pip install`, because I got `error: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/__config__.pyc: Permission denied` without `sudo`. Could that be the issue?

Comment: yes, if you got this error it means it wasnt installed. Does `pip show scipy` show the updated version after that `sudo pip install`?

Comment: No, `pip show scipy` only shows 0.13.1, even though the 0.14.0 version is there in `site-packages`. But why would this happen if I get `Successfully installed scipy` in the end? Is it time to take this to git issues?

Comment: So doing `rm .../site-packages/scipy-0.13.1-py2.7.egg-info` did the trick, and now only `scipy` 0.14.0 is recognized (which is correct) but this seems against the philosophies of `pip`

Comment: that sounds strange, but I'm glad you've solved it .)